# RASA: Automatic generation of stories

Tags: chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I want to know whether it is possible to automatically generate stories to train the chatbot using RASA. 
I have built my training data using the online training session to generate the stories and I found it very impractical. I would like to know whether there is some automatic way to do the story conversion of any conversation.

Comment: you have to better detail the probelm. Afterward what you mean with "automattically generate". Maybe you need to just write stories.md file

Answer (score 1):

You can use interactive learning to create training data while speaking to the bot. See the docs [here](http://rasa.com/docs/rasa/core/interactive-learning/) for more information on how to use interactive learning.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably too late of a response but it is for the rest of the community who might still need an answer to this. A few months ago, I personally experienced that it would take too long to conduct interactive learning to train your RASA bot (especially when you have hundreds of intents and actions).

What I did was:

1) Compile all my named intents and actions(utter_) into a .csv file with following column headers : [subject] | [intent_name] | [utter_name]

2) Parse the intent name along with its respective action name in the same row into Markdown(.md) format while adding the respective strings to follow the formatting of the stories.md file

Package this into a function and call in a for loop:

```
     subcell = "## " + column[0] + "\n" # [subject] header for stories
     subcell += "* " + column[1] + "\n" + "  - " + column[2] + "\n" + "\n" # [intent_name] + [utter_name]
```

3) The generated stories.md output will have all the direct intent-action pairings for your simple conversation flows. Likewise, you can apply this concept for generating domain.yml

Hope this helps!

Comment: your propsal just translates a "story" file from a CSV to the required MD format. It could be enough, just if stories are single-turn FAQ (1 intent in input -> 1 answer) and you could have millions of these "stateless" (but also a bit "useless") cases. Ok but, stories scope (and interactive learning) is to realize conversational complex/contextual interactions. Here just a single story is chain of many intents-reply !